# What can we infer from a growth bound What can we infer from the condition $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left\|A_n\right\|}n\le0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, dynamical-systems, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $A_n$ be a compact linear operator on a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space $H$. What can we infer from the condition $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left\|A_n\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}}n\le0\tag1$$ and in which sense is related to the asymptotic stability?

$(1)$ reminds me of the growth bound of a $C^0$-semigroup. Is there a natural relation to it?

I know that $\left\|A_n\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}$ is equal to the largest singular value of $A_n$. Moreover, $(1)$ immediately yields that $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists N\in\mathbb N:\forall n\ge N:\left\|A_n\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}<e^{\varepsilon n}\tag2.$$ But a bound by an exponential seems to be of little use to me (and I guess this is heavily wrong). So, what's the use of it?

If you need more context, $(1)$ is the condition imposed by Goldsheid and Margulis in the paper [Lyapunov indices of a product of random matrices](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM1989v044n05ABEH002214/meta), Proposition 1.3, equation 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the same as for a strongly continuous semigroup only because this is used differently there.

Namely, you should then have a **single** generator and here you have something depending on $n$, so you would first need to consider an "autonomization" of the dynamics" or say start discussing a generalization of the bounded growth condition, more or less as in A. Pazy, *Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations*, Applied Mathematical Sciences $44$, Springer-Verlag, New York, $1983$, specifically in Chapter 5, although I note that this is somewhat outdated by now.

Here it just means that one element does not change the asymtptotic properties of the composition, and that's the usual approach, as in Raghunathan's work.
Condition (1) is the usual one (and it is used regularly). More precisely, essentially it allows one to show that the eigenvectors obtained from the singular values converge, thus giving the splitting in the multiplicative ergodic theorem.

It is also hidden in the proof that (1) guarantees that the Lyapunov indices are finite.

Comment: With Lyapunoiv indices, you mean $\lambda(x) =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left\|A_nx\right\|}n$, right? (a) Why are they defined this way? This seems to be counterintuitive. It would make more sense to me to define $\mu(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|A_nx\right\|^{\frac1n}$ instead, since not $\lambda(x)$, but $\mu(x)=e^{\lambda(x)}$ are the eigenvalues of the limiting operator $A:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(A^\ast A)^{\frac1{2n}}$. Am I missing something? And can you tell me how we can interpret $A$? (b) What's the intuition why $(1)$ guarantees they are finite?

Comment: You are referring to Goldsheid and Margulis. These are defined right in the beginning of their introduction. For other question, please write them separated.

Comment: Yes, I know how they are defined. The question is why they aren't defined to be $\mu$ instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3662978/47771,

Comment: Have I replied to your question here?

Comment: If you mean, if your answer answers this question, then yes.

Comment: You wrote that $(1)$ ensures that "one element does not change the asymtptotic properties of the composition". With "one element" you mean one of the factors $A_i$ in the product $B_n=A_n\cdots A_1$? How is this ensured by $(1)$?

Comment: Indeed, note that $\|B_{n+1}x\|\le \|A_n\|\cdot\|B_{n}x\|$.

Comment: That's clear, but I still don't get it. What I'm able to infer from $(1)$ is only that, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ it holds $\left\|A_n\right\|<e^{\varepsilon n}$.

Comment: For that you need to follow the technical details of the proof of Raghunathan (followed by Goldsheid and Margulis), which is impossible to reproduce here. As you know (1) is not the only hypothesis in the theorem (although it is in your question), so you need to use the rest as well.